# Re-usable pointer to template base type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I have a parameterized, pure virtual base class, whose only purpose is to act as an interface for derived classes:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
public:
  virtual T get() = 0;
};
```

Then, I have concrete subclasses, which are essentially factories. Each returns a different type of object:

```
class DerivedOne : Base< vector<int> > {
public:
  // ctors, etc.
  vector<int> get();
};

class DerivedTwo : Base< map<double> > {
public:
  // ctors, etc.
  map<double> get();
};
```

So far, so good. But in the client code, I want to use a pointer to the base class, and use it to create objects from the derived classes. Here's an example:

```
Base* creator;
vector<int> stuffOne;
map<double> stuffTwo;

creator = new DerivedOne();
stuffOne = creator->get();
delete creator;

creator = new DerivedTwo();
stuffTwo = creator->get();
delete creator;
```

But this won't work, because you can't have a pointer to a parameterized type without specifying the parameter type. So, `creator` could be a `Base< vector<int> >*` or a `Base< map<double> >*`, but not simply a `Base*`.

This defeats the whole purpose of using a pointer, and allocating/de-allocating derived objects. (As you could guess, the real-world derived objects hold a lot of memory, so destroying them during runtime is desirable.)

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've taken a look at abstract factories, but they don't exactly do what I need. I explicitly set this up so that the client code wouldn't be any more complicated than what it is now.

EDIT: What I'm trying to avoid is the use of distinct pointers for each of the derived classes. This would work with the code as it is now:

```
DerivedOne* d1 = new DerivedOne();
stuffOne = d1->get();
delete d1;

DerivedTwo* d2 = new DerivedTwo();
stuffTwo = d2->get();
delete d2;
```

...but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a factory pattern? Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you mix a pointer and RTTI (which are runtime concepts), and templates (which are compile time concepts). The compiler needs type information to instantiate the templates, but you're trying to hide that type information in RTTI.

Comment: Since you already know statically that `stuffOne` and `stuffTwo` have different types, and you know the types, you might as well just have distinct factories for each type and not try to shoehorn some common base into it.

Comment: @Jens: You could be right. I am coming from Java, which has generics (and no pointers, of course.)

Comment: @Kerrek: So, I would just have concrete DerivedOne and DerivedTwo objects, then?

Comment: @littleadv: Sorry, to answer your question: these are actually classes that read vectors/maps of objects from CSV files. The Base class's template parameter specifies the type of object to read; the Derived classes read one type of object from a single CSV file.

Comment: @Karl so you *are* trying to implement a factory pattern. Why not do it properly then?

Comment: At least I'd have one separate hierarchy per type...

Comment: @littleadv: because the same problem would happen with a factory. The factory would produce objects of different types, which would have to be pointed at by separate pointers. That's no better than what I have now.

Comment: Well IMO, you need a class to parse CSVs. Then a factory, that can use this builder, and can build two types of objects. The only change you would need for the final user would be writing `factory->getStuffOne()` and `factory->getStuffTwo()` or something similar instead of just `factory->get()`. I don't think there are any facilities that would pick up correct version based on `rhs`. But maybe some one can invent some magic, with overloading `operator=`. Still, I guess that explicit call is not a big problem, since user already knows the type they want.

Comment: The problem's source here is that your produce to different objects with different types that do not have a common base (std::vector and std::map). As long as this will stand you're problem will remain. You do not use a map the same way you use a vector, in your head they might look similar (and that's probably why you only provided one of the two template parameters of map..) but from a type point of view they are not :)

Comment: @Drax: Even if I used std::vector for everything, the problem would remain. `DerivedOne` would return `std::vector<int>`, and `DerivedTwo` would return `std::vector<double>`. You'd still need a template.

Comment: @luk32: The system is (supposed to be) designed such that objects do not NEED to read from CSV files. For example, `DerivedOneSubclass` could read from a database (and still return the same `std::vector<int>`). That's not clear from my example, of course, but it may give you some idea of why I did it this way.

Comment: @KarlGiesing That's exactly what i'm saying, you're returning different things and you want to use them as if they were the same things. As long as there is no common base between the two and your processing functions are not templates, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: There is no way to do this. I must have separate pointers for each derived class.

The consensus seems to be that I need to create a factory. That is, instead of DerivedOne and DerivedTwo, I have a factory class that has methods which return different data types and container types.